# No automatic scrolling in Typescript is working in my Angular Nebular Application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-routing, nebular

I have the issue that after a router.navigatedByUrl(""), I want to scroll to the top again.

I tried following methods which all not worked :

1. window.scroll(0,0);
2. document.body.scrollTop = 0;
3. document.querySelector('body').scrollTo(0,0);
4. NbLayoutScrollService.scrollTo(0,0); // Nebular Service for scrolling
5. viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
6. document.querySelector().scrollTo(0,0); /* Since ive read that there is a problem in Angular 8 with material, in which the scroll hook has to be on a different html element than the body */

I tried those methods in this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => { ... }; and also with the following:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
  onActivate(event) {
    ...
   }
```

Router events did not even trigger, but the second method triggered but the scrolling methods did not work.

Ive get the warning "A router outlet has not been instantiated during routes activation. URL Segment: " , is this maybe the reason that scrolling is not working?

The application is running on Angular Version 10.1.1, I gladly take any suggestions on what to research this problem, but currently I am on a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code inside your onActivate method to move back to top

```
onActivate(event) {
 window.setInterval(function() {
    var pos = window.pageYOffset;
    if ( pos > 0 ) {
        window.scrollTo( 0, pos - 20 ); // how far to scroll on each step
    } else {
        window.clearInterval( scrollToTop );
    }
}, 16);
}
```